# How can I select the max for a maths operation and also other elements without the max displaying all results

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to find the maximum value of something, while also selecting other attributes at the same time. When i do the max statement on its own, it works as intended, but when I select another attribute it displays every attribute as if the max statement wasn't there. How do I get this to work?

code that works:

```
select max(contract_end - contract_start)
from contract
```

code that returns all data, not just the max:

```
select contract_id, emp_name, job_desc, max(contract_end - contract_start)
from contract join employer on emp_id = contract_client
              join job on job_id = contract_job
group by contract_id, emp_name, job_desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read it, would your query - slightly modified, so that it uses the `MAX` function in its **analytic** form - do the job?

```
select contract_id, 
       emp_name, 
       job_desc, 
       max(contract_end - contract_start) over (order by null) max_end_start
from contract join employer on emp_id = contract_client
              join job on job_id = contract_job
```

---

Or, is this what you're looking for? Use the `MAX` date difference as a subquery:

```
select contract_id, 
       emp_name, 
       job_desc,
       contract_end - contract_start diff
from contract join employer on emp_id = contract_client
              join job on job_id = contract_job
where contract_end - contract_start = (select max(contract_end - contract_start)
                                       from contract
                                      )
```

Comment: That selected all the rows with their max_end_start value all set at the max, I just want the one row with the data for the highest

Comment: I added another example; see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max over the whole table, then just `order by` and `fetch first`:

```
select c.contract_id, e.emp_name, j.job_desc, 
    c.contract_end - c.contract_start as contract_duration
from contract c
inner join employer e on e.emp_id = c.contract_client
inner join job j on j.job_id = c.contract_job
order by contract_duration desc
fetch first row with ties
```

`with ties` allows top ties, if any.

Note that I added table aliases and prefixed all columns with the table they belong to (I made a few guesses, that you might need to review).

The `fetch` clause is available in Oracle 12. In earlier versions, you can use window functions instead:

```
select *
from (
    select c.contract_id, e.emp_name, j.job_desc, 
        c.contract_end - c.contract_start as contract_duration,
        rank() over(order by contract_duration desc) rn
    from contract c
    inner join employer e on e.emp_id = c.contract_client
    inner join job j on j.job_id = c.contract_job
) t
where rn = 1
```

Finally: if you want the latest row *per group* (which is not what your question suggests), then you can just add a `partition by` clause to `rank()`, enumerating the columns that define the group.

Comment: That returns multiple rows when I only want the highest?

Comment: @anotherwildeboy: this gives one row, with the max value. If there is more than one row with the maximum value, then it gives several rows. Give the query a try and see by yourself.